# Mark nodes in an axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, axis

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work. I got an error:

> ./tabtest.tex:37: Undefined control sequence. 
> <argument> \xc 
> ,\yc 
> l.37       \end{axis}

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tikz,filecontents}
%
\begin{document} 
    \begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
         0.84661730E-01  0.53453308E+00 -
         0.37594643E+00  0.38930386E+00 +
         0.54111367E+00  0.94450973E-02 +
         0.38930386E+00 -0.37594646E+00 -
         0.94450731E-02 -0.54111367E+00 -
        -0.37594652E+00 -0.38930380E+00 +
        -0.54111367E+00 -0.94451150E-02 +
        -0.38930374E+00  0.37594658E+00 -
    \end{filecontents}
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal, axis lines=none, xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1, clip=false]
            \coordinate (OP) at (0,0);
            \draw [black] (OP) circle (1);
            %
            \pgfplotstableread[header=false]{data.txt}{\datatable}
            \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\rownum}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
            %
            \addplot[mark=none] table {\datatable};
            %
            \foreach \angle in {0,...,\rownum}{%
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\angle}{[index]0}\of{\datatable}
                \let\xc\pgfplotsretval
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\angle}{[index]1}\of{\datatable}
                \let\yc\pgfplotsretval
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\angle}{[index]2}\of{\datatable}
                \let\ps\pgfplotsretval
                \node at (\xc,\yc) {\ps};
            }%
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Does `\addplot[mark=none, nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=center, point meta=explicit symbolic] table [meta index=2] {\datatable};` do what you want? Instead of the `\foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you! I got the figure that I want. By the way, regardless of that result, the question on the error is still valid.